# Access gridview as property from usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have gridview bind in user control and want to access that gridview from user control in page and use export to excel.

I created property in usercontrol to access but I am not able to access it.

How can I access gridview from usercontrol in my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you write ExportToExcel method into the user control or just make a property which is public and return the refference to the grid:

```
public GridView MyGrid
{
    get{ return this.GridView1;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using `interface`.

You can create an interface and implement it on the web page. And using a interface object in usercontrol, you can call the interface method.

eg,
Interface

```
public interface IExport
{
    void Export();
}
```

Your web page

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page, IExport
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UC11.MyExport = this;
        //UC11 will be whatever name of your usercontrol
    }

    public void Export()
    {
        //your export code
    }
}
```

And your usercontorl

```
public partial class UC1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public IExport MyExport { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyExport.Export();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if you use **Master page** for your aspx pages you can access your page GridView in your user control in this way

```
 Page mypage= this.Page;
  GridView mypageGridview = (GridView)mypage.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("YourGridView");
```

if you have not master page

```
 Page mypage= this.Page;
    GridView mypageGridview = (GridView)mypage.FindControl("YourGridView");
```